# mapply multiple undefined arguments

Tags: r, arguments, mapply

Assume you have an undefined nr of lists as possible arguments for a function, for example the following 3 can be picked (this example is as simple as possible, so vectors are stored in lists):

```
a <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5))
b <- list(c(3,6,7,2,1))
c <- list(c(3,9,8))
```

If I want to calculate the intersection of all three lists, this can be done as follows:

```
Map(intersect,c,Map(intersect,a,b))
# or equivalent:
mapply(intersect,c,mapply(intersect,a,b,SIMPLIFY=F))
# [1] 3
```

But how can I change the nr of arguments to be undefined? I read about `...`, but I cannot get it to work. First idea was to write a function, that can have multiple list arguments defined by `...`:

```
intersectio <- function(...){
  Map(function(...){
    intersect(...)
  })
}
```

Q: But that doesn't work of course, because intersect must be applied recursively. Is there any way to achieve this in R?

Q2: Here is an updated example with a nested list structure. How can it be done in this case, i.e. intersect every sublist of the parent list with the associated sublist (same index) of the other parent lists?

```
a <- list(list(c(1,2,3,4,5)),list(c(3,6,7,2,1)),list(c(3,9,8)))
b <- list(list(c(1,2)),list(c(3,6,9,11,12)),list(c(3)))
c <- list(list(c(1,9)),list(c(65,23,12)),list(c(14,15)))
```

Comment: intersectio <- function(...){  Reduce(intersect,...)} does not work either. Moreover, my arguments are actually nested lists and not simple vectors in lists, as above. So it's not that easy as just to apply Reduce...

Comment: Maybe `Reduce(function(x, y) Map(intersect, x, y), list(a, b, c))`? You need to provide a representative reproducible example.

Comment: For your example, this should work: `Reduce(intersect, c(...))`

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments so far, both work for my initial example. I am currently working to make a nested-list example that is more representative of my data str/problem, as was suggested

Comment: Seems this works: `mapply(function(...) Reduce(intersect, c(...)), a, b, c)`

Comment: yep it does. Why do you use `c(...)` here?

Comment: Because `Reduce` expects a list as input. So you have to concatenate your lists into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Roland suggested, you can use `Reduce` to solve your problem. In the case of flat lists (as in the first version of the question), you can use the following:

```
Reduce(intersect, c(a, b, c))
```

In the case of nested lists (as in the updated question), you can just have to wrap that inside a `mapply` call:

```
mapply(function(...) Reduce(intersect, c(...)), a, b, c)
```

To generalize, you can define a function and then call it with as many arguments as you want.

```
list_intersect <- function(...){
  mapply(function(...) Reduce(intersect, c(...)), ...) 
}
list_intersect(a, b, c)
```

Comment: very good. Just one more thing: Here we do it for a, b and c. What would the solution look like if we wanted to generalze it for an undefined amount of arguments? I cannot simply replace a, b and c by `...`